# How to go back to previous page if back button is pressed in WebView?

Tags: android, android-webview

I have an app in which I have a `WebView` where I display some websites. It works, clicking a link in the webpage goes to the next page in the website inside my app. But when I click the phone's back button, it takes me straight into my app. I want to go back to the previous page in the website  instead. How can I do this?

Here is the code sample I'm using:

```
public class Webdisplay extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
        setContentView(R.layout.webdisplay);

        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS,
                Window.PROGRESS_VISIBILITY_ON); 

        Toast loadingmess = Toast.makeText(this,
                "Cargando El Diario de Hoy", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        loadingmess.show();

        WebView myWebView;

        myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.elsalvador.com");
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        myWebView.setInitialScale(1);
        myWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

        final Activity MyActivity = this;
        myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() 
        {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)   
            {
                MyActivity.setTitle("Loading...");
                MyActivity.setProgress(progress * 100); 

                if(progress == 100)
                    MyActivity.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: For xwalkview refer to [How to use back button to go back with XWalkView of CrossWalk, or disable it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40968633/6521116)

Answer (score 592, accepted):

I use something like this in my activities with WebViews:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                if (mWebView.canGoBack()) {
                    mWebView.goBack();
                } else {
                    finish();
                }
                return true;
        }

    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Edit:

For this code to work, you need to add a field to the `Activity` containing the WebView:

```
private WebView mWebView;
```

Initialize it in the `onCreate()` method and you should be good to go.

```
mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
```

Comment: were should I place that code? under all my code? or just under the loasUrl just like the builtinZoom?

Comment: You'd put it inside your activity, but outside the onCreate() method.

Comment: when I place your code it gives me an error for the mWebView variable since is out of the oncreate, where should I place that variable?

Comment: you need to put it inside activity, but before onCreate, see edit.

Comment: instead of `finish()` put `return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event)`

Comment: or in fact just simply remove whole `else` block

Comment: I think the below answer (@Kevin's one) would be better.. anyway.. GG ;)

Comment: I used this code but not working in my app. but I am testing it on Emulator. how to test it on emulator?

Comment: Remove the `else` block. This way the volume buttons doesn't close the application

Comment: @RobinF the else block would not have any effect on the volume buttons the way the code is written because of the switch/case. The only thing removing the else block does is cause it not to ever close the activity with the back button.

Answer (score 349):

If using Android 2.2 and above (which is most devices now), the following code will get you what you want.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (webView.canGoBack()) {
        webView.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice. I use a variation of this answer, but without the "else" block. Otherwise when the user presses back too many times they end up at a blank app "start" screen, with no option for the user to move forward.

Comment: This looks like the most appropriate answer.  @CaffeineComa, you could probably just code your app start screen to not show in the app "activity" history.  Just add `android:noHistory="true"` attribute in the `<activity>` you want, in the AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Should this `return;`?  It does in the [training guide](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html#back-webviews).

Comment: I love u so much

Answer (score 136):

This is my solution. It works also in Fragment.

```
webView.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            WebView webView = (WebView) v;
            
            switch(keyCode) {
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                    if (webView.canGoBack()) {
                        webView.goBack();
                        return true;
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
        
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: this my opinion, this should be the proper answer.

Comment: Why this answer should be the proper answer? Any issue with the top two answers?

Comment: @dc7a9163d9 an activity might want to have several views or objects that depend on keyDown. this answer abstracts out the need for the activity to keydown dependency via webview (which is better design). also, newer apps almost exclusively use fragments as opposed to activities, and this answer supports that use case as opposed to the others

Comment: I like this approach. Instead of the whole activity listening just the WebView

Comment: Agree this is better, so the main activity doesn't need to hold a WebView only used by fragments.

Comment: SUPERB! Thanks, this is especially useful in a Fragment! Thanks!

Comment: This is what i need. Thanks.

Comment: How to reload previous page ?

Comment: This excellent solution naturally requires that the `WebView` has focus. If necessary, Issue `webView.requestFocus()` (for example in the case of a `Fragment` that is visible alongside the UI of its parent `Activity`)

Comment: @Arvin It depends. In my case I want the back button to back the webview, even if other views have focus.

Comment: Wow. This is solution for last Kotlin! I searched it too many days and this is works!

Answer (score 21):

Full reference for next button and progress bar : [put back and next button in webview](https://demonuts.com/webview-back-forward/)

If you want to go to back page when click on phone's back button, use this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (webView.canGoBack()) {
        webView.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

You can also create custom back button like this:

```
btnback.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if (wv.canGoBack()) {
                wv.goBack();
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 17):

**Focusing should also be checked in onBackPressed**

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mWebview.isFocused() && mWebview.canGoBack()) {
            mWebview.goBack();       
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
            finish();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sounds plausible, could you please explain why?

Answer (score 14):

Why not use `onBackPressed()`?

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // super.onBackPressed(); Do not call me!

    // Go to the previous web page.
}
```

Comment: because only sdk 2.2 and higher supports this method .. it doesn't work with sdk 1.6

Comment: otoh, Honeycomb and newer don't have a hardware back key, resulting in onKeyDown never being called.

Answer (score 12):

here is a code with confirm exit:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        if(webView.canGoBack()){
            webView.goBack();
        }else{
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
            .setTitle("Exit!")
            .setMessage("Are you sure you want to close?")
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    finish();    
                }

            })
            .setNegativeButton("No", null)
            .show();    
        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 12):

In kotlin:

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
    when {
        webView.canGoBack() -> webView.goBack()
        else -> super.onBackPressed()
    }
}
```

webView - id of the webview component in xml, if using synthetic reference.

Answer (score 6):

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // Check if the key event was the Back button and if there's history
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && myWebView.canGoBack()) {
        myWebView.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    // If it wasn't the Back key or there's no web page history, bubble up to the default
    // system behavior (probably exit the activity)
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
 WebView mWebView;

 mWebView = findViewById(R.id.webView);

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

The first answer by FoamyGuy is correct but I have some additions; low reputations cannot allow me to do comments. If for some reasons your page fails to load, ensure that you set a flag to take note of the failure and then check it on the onBackPressed override. Otherwise your **canGoBack()** *will be forever executed without heading* to the actual back activity if it was there:

```
//flag with class wide access 
public boolean ploadFailFlag = false;

//your error handling override
@Override
public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest req, WebResourceError rerr) {
    onReceivedError(view, rerr.getErrorCode(), rerr.getDescription().toString(), req.getUrl().toString());
    ploadFailFlag = true;       //note this change 
    .....
    .....
}

//finally to the answer to this question:
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(checkinWebView.canGoBack()){
        //if page load fails, go back for web view will not go back - no page to go to - yet overriding the super 
        if(ploadFailFlag){
            super.onBackPressed();
        }else {
            checkinWebView.goBack();
        }
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "super:", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think I'm a little late but according to the [android documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-custom-back), you can have custom back navigation inside fragments done by the following piece of code.

```
 requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this) {
            // Handle the back button event
            if (binding.webView.canGoBack()){
                binding.webView.goBack()
            } else {
                findNavController().popBackStack()
            }
        }
```

you can customize what to do when you the webView cant go back as per your needs.

Answer (score 2):

If someone wants to handle backPressed for a webView inside a *fragment*, then he can use below code.

1. Copy below code into your `Activity` class (that contains a fragment `YourFragmmentName`)

   ```
   @Override
   public void onBackPressed() {
   List<Fragment> fragmentList = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments();

   boolean handled = false;
   for(Object f: fragmentList) {
       if(f instanceof YourFragmentName) {
           handled = ((YourFragmentName)f).onBackPressed();
           if(handled) {
               break;
           }
       }
   }

   if(!handled) {
       super.onBackPressed();
   }
   ```

   }
2. Copy this code in the fragment `YourFragmentName`

   ```
   public boolean onBackPressed() {
      if (webView.canGoBack()) {
          webView.goBack();
          return true;
      } else {
          return false;
      }
   }
   ```

**Notes**

- `Activity` should be replaced with the actual Acitivity class you are using.
- `YourFragmentName` should be replaced with the name of your Fragment.
- Declare `webView` in `YourFragmentName` so that it can be accessed from within the function.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this for webview in a fragment:

```
private lateinit var webView: WebView

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_name, container, false)
    webView = root!!.findViewById(R.id.home_web_view)
    var url: String = "http://yoururl.com"
    webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
    webView.webViewClient = WebViewClient()
    webView.loadUrl(url)
    webView.canGoBack()
    webView.setOnKeyListener{ v, keyCode, event ->
        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP
            && webView.canGoBack()){
            webView.goBack()
            return@setOnKeyListener true
        }
        false
    }
    return root
}
```

Comment: Why do you call `webView.canGoBack()` before `setOnKeyListener`?

Answer (score 1):

You should the following libraries on your class handle the onBackKeyPressed.
canGoBack() checks whether the webview can reference to the previous page. If it is possible then use the goBack() function to reference the previous page (go back).

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if( mWebview.canGoBack()){
        mWebview.goBack(); 
    } else {
        //Do something else. like trigger pop up. Add rate app or see more app
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Kotlin solution:

```
override fun onKeyUp(keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent?): Boolean {
    if (event?.action != ACTION_UP || event.keyCode != KEYCODE_BACK) {
        return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event)
    }

    if (mWebView.canGoBack()) {
        mWebView.goBack()
    } else {
        finish()
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Official Kotlin Way:

```
override fun onKeyDown(keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent?): Boolean {
    // Check if the key event was the Back button and if there's history
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && myWebView.canGoBack()) {
        myWebView.goBack()
        return true
    }
    // If it wasn't the Back key or there's no web page history, bubble up to the default
    // system behavior (probably exit the activity)
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event)
}
```

https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#NavigatingHistory

Answer (score -4):

use this code to go back on page and when last page came then go out of activity

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        Intent intent=new Intent(LiveImage.this,DashBoard.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```