# Error implementing back button on webview fragment android using handler

Tags: android, android-fragments, webview

Here is my code for fragment that contains a webview, I'm trying to implement back button for webview, and my code doesn't work.. Have tried plenty of answers online, but it doesn't seem to work for my code..
Basically I tried it using handlers with the help of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10631749/2768665), and I see the below error..

[image: This is the error, which I'm getting when I compile it..]

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Message;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.app.Fragment;

import com.gururaju.verve15.R;
import java.util.logging.Handler;

public final class LoginFragment extends Fragment {

    public LoginFragment(){}

    static WebView mWeb;
    private View mContentView;

    private Handler handler = new Handler(){
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message message) {
            switch (message.what) {
                case 1:{
                    webViewGoBack();
                }break;
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        mContentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, null);
        mWeb = (WebView)mContentView.findViewById(R.id.webView);


        WebSettings settings = mWeb.getSettings();
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        settings.setSupportZoom(false);
        mWeb.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        mWeb.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
        mWeb.loadUrl("http://example.com/login/");
        mWeb.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener(){

            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWeb.canGoBack()) {
                    handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }

        });

    }

    private void webViewGoBack(){
        mWeb.goBack();
    }
}
```

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `import java.util.logging.Handler;`
to `import android.os.Handler`

Comment: doing this cleared 2 of my errors,
and the last error im left with is `cannot find symbol class OnKeyListener`

Comment: Obviously you have imported wrong `Handler`. What's the error now?

Comment: Change `new OnKeyListener()` to `new View.OnKeyListener()` or add `import android.view.View.OnKeyListener;`

Comment: the last comment of yours worked! I did mess up while importing the OnKeyListener. 

Many Thanks! :)

Comment: Another problem now, If the back button is pressed and if the history isn't present, it is killing my app, `Unfortunately APP has stopped`

Comment: I debugged it myself, had some problem in my MainActivity :)