# Goback Function in Fragment Webview

Tags: android, android-fragments, webview

how can we add goBack function in webview fragment?

when I click BACK button, it quits from fragment, I want it not to finish, but load the old website.

I tried ,[this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24267114/5400003) but changed some words and it s not working...

please help.

code is here;

FRAGMENT ACTIVITY;

```
    package info.androidhive.materialtabs.activity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewFragment;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import info.androidhive.materialtabs.R;
import info.androidhive.materialtabs.fragments.OneFragment;
import info.androidhive.materialtabs.fragments.ThreeFragment;
import info.androidhive.materialtabs.fragments.TwoFragment;

public class SimpleTabsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_simple_tabs);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);


    }


    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new OneFragment(), "ONE");
        adapter.addFragment(new TwoFragment(), "TWO");
        adapter.addFragment(new ThreeFragment(), "THREE");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);


    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }





    }
}
```

FRAGMENT LAYOUT;

```html
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add "Go Back" function in WebView inside Fragment?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10631425/how-to-add-go-back-function-in-webview-inside-fragment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override the onBackPressed method from your Activity.
From there try to find your current fragment and call a method from this fragment that will handle your web views action

Example (This code belongs to your Activity):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container) instanceof YourFragment) {
        YourFragment currentFragment = (YourFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container);
        if (currentFragment != null) {
            currentFragment.handleWebViewNavigation();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: R.id.container is the xml element that contains your fragment I don't know how you called it!

Comment: Can you post more code (Activity and it's xml description)?

Comment: I added them to main question.. could you check?

Comment: try changing R.id.container to R.id.viewpager

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can not do directly inside the fragment. The `onBackPressed` can be overridden in the `FragmentActivity`. What you can do is:

1. Override the `onBackPressed` inside the activity.
2. When the  `onBackPressed` is called, check if the instance of the current fragment is the instance showing the `webview`.
3. If it is, ask the `fragment` if  the `webview` can go back.
4. if it is not, call the `super` or whatever you need

for more detail visit this [How to add "Go Back" function in WebView inside Fragment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10631425/how-to-add-go-back-function-in-webview-inside-fragment)