# Fragment webview back button not working

Tags: android, android-fragments, webview

At my `navigationDrawer` from menu , by clicking search it opens a specific `webview` in a `fragment` . Works fine, but when I press back on that `webview` - instead of getting the last visited `webscreen` it comes back to my main `fragment`. how can i solve this? I'm providing my `fragment` java file here. please mention any other codes to need (if needed) to solve my problem

---

```
public class GoogleFragment extends Fragment {

public WebView mWebView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(fragment_google, container, false);
    mWebView = (WebView) v.findViewById(webview);
    mWebView.loadUrl("https://google.com");

    // Enable Javascript
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    //improve webview performance
    mWebView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
    mWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
    mWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    mWebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NARROW_COLUMNS);
    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webSettings.setSavePassword(true);
    webSettings.setSaveFormData(true);
    webSettings.setEnableSmoothTransition(true);

    // Force links and redirects to open in the WebView instead of in a browser
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    return v;
}

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add "Go Back" function in WebView inside Fragment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10631425/how-to-add-go-back-function-in-webview-inside-fragment)

Answer (score 0):

I think when you press back button from fragment than we need to handle it inside of Activity,

You need to first **Override** *onBackPressed()* method in your **main activity** which having fragment and **global** assign **Webview** with public in your google fragment

**NOTE** : when you are adding or replacing fragment keep adding a **TAG**, it can be helpful for getting instance of fragment.

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
     Fragment fragment = 
     getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("google_fragment");
     if (fragment instanceof GoogleFragment) {
        if (webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }else{
       super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class GoogleFragment extends Fragment {

public WebView mWebView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(fragment_google, container, false);
    mWebView = (WebView) v.findViewById(webview);
    mWebView.loadUrl("https://google.com");

    // Enable Javascript
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    //improve webview performance


  mWebView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);

  mWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
    mWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    mWebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NARROW_COLUMNS);
    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webSettings.setSavePassword(true);
    webSettings.setSaveFormData(true);
    webSettings.setEnableSmoothTransition(true);

    // Force links and redirects to open in the WebView instead of in a browser
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

v.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
v.requestFocus();

v.setOnKeyListener( new View.OnKeyListener()
{
@Override
public boolean onKey( View v1, int keyCode, KeyEvent event )
{
if( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK ) {


if(mWebView.canGoBack())
{
wView.goBack();
wView.getUrl();
}


return true;
}
return false;
}
} );
    return v1;
}
}

Please try this code .it may help you.
```