# Handle onBackPressed in android in fragment

Tags: java, android

I want to handle `onBackPressed` in **fragment**

I use following code in my **activity** but this return 0

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

    int count = getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();

    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), ""+count, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if (count == 1) {
        super.onBackPressed();
        //additional code
    } else {
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }

}
```

Comment: You'll need call `addToBackStack()` when calling commit on `Fragment` in order to `getBackStackEntryCount()` or else it'll always give you **0**.

Comment: Did you use `.addToBackStack(null)` when you added the fragment?

Comment: Can you show the part where you are adding Fragment ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement onBackPressed() in Fragments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448653/how-to-implement-onbackpressed-in-fragments)

Comment: **Check this link for perfect solution** https://stackoverflow.com/a/67086466/8572350

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `.addToBackStack(null)` in your `Activity` or `Fragment` . When you adding or replacing `fragment`. Like below

```
 getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.parent_layout, new MyFragment()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Note:- you don't have to do anything in your `onBackPressed()` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
Just app this line when you want to replace any fragment and manage backsack on Fragment.

ClientHome per = new ClientHome();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("usertype", "client");
                per.setArguments(bundle);
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_from_left, R.anim.slide_to_right);
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, per, "tag");
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("tag");
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
```