# How to go to previous page in Webview present in a Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, webview, searchbar, onbackpressed

I have an actvity called SearchActivity. It has a searchbar and 4 tabs with Webviews. When I enter text and click on search, all the tabs are loading respective urls that I'm passing to them. But when I click on back button I want all the webviews to go back to the previous page, instead the activity closes. I've tried the below code, but it doesn't work. This the code of SearchActivity

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    int count = getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();

    if (count != 0 && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webView.canGoBack()) {
        webView.goBack();
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        //additional code
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10631425/how-to-add-go-back-function-in-webview-inside-fragment

Comment: I've used that one too. It doesn't work.

Comment: You have not added the callback of onBackPressed() in Fragment. Kindly follow this link and implement the onBackPressed into the fragment, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448653/how-to-implement-onbackpressed-in-fragments

Answer (score 2):

1.Add an interface on `SearchActivity` and implement that interface on `MyFragment` to communicate between `SearchActivity` and `MyFragment`.

2.Override `onBackPressed()` method of `SearchActivity` to add custom functions when the back button is pressed and check if fragment's `WebView` can go back via `goBack` listener. If can go back, then do so. If can not, call `super.onBackPressed()`.

SearchActivity.java

```
public class SearchActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

public interface goBack{
    boolean canGoBack();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
   //fragment_container is a layout where fragment is populated

    if (fragment instanceof goBack && fragment.canGoBack()) {
        return;
    }
    super.onBackPressed();

}
}
```

MyFragment.java

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements SearchActivity.goBack{
@Override
public boolean canGoBack() {
    if (webView.canGoBack()) {

        webView.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: The `Webview` is present in Fragment. How can I access it from the activity?

Comment: What is `fragment_container`?

Comment: see the comment where `fragment_container ` is mentioned. Its a layout (like `FrameLayout`) id where fragment is populated

Answer (score 1):

I would use an interface:

```
Public Interface InterfaceBackPressed {
    onInterfaceBackPressed();
}
```

Then in your Activity:

```
public class SearchActivity extends Activity {
...
    @Override public void onBackPressed() {
    Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container);
       if (!(fragment instanceof InterfaceBackPressed) || !((InterfaceBackPressed) fragment).onBackPressed()) {
          super.onInterfaceBackPressed();
       }
    } 
}
```

and have every fragment implement your interface:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements IOnBackPressed{
   @Override
   public void onInterfaceBackPressed() {
       if (webView.canGoBack()) {

            webView.goBack(); 
        } else {
        super.onInterfaceBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```