# Web view in Fragment

Tags: javascript, android, android-fragments, android-webview

I'm new to Android Studio and learning and help me to short out my issues. I'm unable to add `onBackpress` method in my `webview` fragment:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View myView = inflater.inflate ( R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    WebView myWebView = myView.findViewById ( R.id.home_webView );
    myWebView.loadUrl ( "https://yahoo.com" );
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings ();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled ( true );
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return myView;
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
      if (webView.canGoBack()) {
          webView.goBack();
      } else super.onBackPressed ();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10631425/how-to-add-go-back-function-in-webview-inside-fragment

Comment: Check this link I think this will help you to solve your issue.
[link for the back press in fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61625313/13261376)