# Back button in WebView not working correctly

Tags: android, kotlin, button, webview, back

I want to use the back button of Android to go back into a WebView (it's in a Fragment), so I put up this code in Kotlin:

```
catWebView.setOnKeyListener { _, keyCode, _ ->
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && catWebView.canGoBack()) {
        catWebView.goBack()
    }
    return@setOnKeyListener true
}
```

and that works, but with a problem: when I tap the back button, the WebView goes all the way back to the first page opened, and not by single steps...

How can I solve it? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Remove your setonkeylistener and Add

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // super.onBackPressed(); Do not call super.onbackpressed!
  
    }
```

Comment: It's in Kotlin, not in Java :)
And I forgot to mention, it's in a Fragment, not in an Activity...

Comment: try this code   https://stackoverflow.com/a/60991211/12916990

Comment: Unfortunately is not working...

Comment: I found a working solution, in case anybody needs: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17652491/14939065