# Android WebView back button causes force close

Tags: java, android, android-webview

Here is my program code. I am new to Android and Java so it may seem messy.  When I press the back button after adding in this code i get a Force Close.

```
    package com.alexriggs.android.gansterstreetwars;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class GangsterStreetWarsActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    final Activity activity = this;
    WebView myWebView;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
        myWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://mafia.itwontwork.net/?pk_campaign=Android&pk_kwd=MainApp");
    }
    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {


        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("mafia.itwontwork.net")) {
                // Designate Urls that you want to load in WebView still.
                return false;
            }           
            // Otherwise, give the default behavior (open in browser)
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
        }
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && myWebView.canGoBack()) {
        myWebView.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

A logcat of the error is here: http://itwontwork.net/logcat/1.txt

I have narrowed it down to the line "myWebView.goBack();". It still does not work even when i take out all the Ifs and just leave that line.

I got the Back button code from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077141/android-webview-how-to-code-the-back-button) and it worked for 18 people. But not me :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you've not actually got an instance of the `WebView` in the `myWebView` *member variable*, only in the *local variable* in the `onCreate` method. (This is why you have a `NullPointerException` when the code runs - `myWebView` hasn't ever been initialized.)

You can fix it by changing the line

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
```

to

```
myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
```

in `onCreate`. (I haven't checked for other errors, but this should fix your problem.)

Comment: This fixed it! I'm sure both answers would have but this seemed the easiest. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Write below line into your code

```
1)  myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

2)  @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            myWebView.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

instead of

```
1)  WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

2)  @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && myWebView.canGoBack()) {
            myWebView.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```