# WebView back button issue in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget, android-webview

I am using WebView to display url inside the application.When I click the back button in device, it terminates and close the application. For eg: i am giving link as

`w.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");`

In that i am searching and it goes to next page inside the webview.But when i click back

button key, it closes the application and not proceeding back to the history what I searched.

How to resolve this.? Any stuff to be given in this, If so, What should be given?

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() { }
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to navigate back through your history in `webview` add this below code to your `webview` activity

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView.canGoBack()) {
         mWebView.goBack();
         return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

u can see both link or below code:-

[How to go back to previous page if back button is pressed in WebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077141/android-webview-how-to-code-the-back-button)

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        switch(keyCode)
        {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
            if(mWebView.canGoBack() == true){
                mWebView.goBack();
            }else{
                finish();
            }
            return true;
        }

    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in that case you need to override back button through this code you can override back button

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {                                              
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)  {
         moveTaskToBack(true);
         return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

u can use below code, it's worked for me.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (Integer.valueOf(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK) < 7 
            && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK
            && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
        // Take care of calling this method on earlier versions of
        // the platform where it doesn't exist.
        onBackPressed();
    }
    return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    return;
}
```