# Enable back button in WebView

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I am just starting out with the Android SDK. I wanted to make a simple app with WebView that displays local web-pages only. I have used examples I have found on the net to make it.

The app works just great, until I want to add a back-button. When the phones back-button is pressed the app crashes.

Here is my **MainActivity.java**

```
package com.hspd.avhor;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    WebView wv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView wv = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.hspd_webview);
        wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        });
        wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/one.htm");
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        if(wv.canGoBack())
            wv.goBack();
        else
            super.onBackPressed();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

And here is my **activity_main.xml**:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/hspd_webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</ScrollView>
```

Here are my errors in **logcat**:

```
04-22 17:48:06.953: W/dalvikvm(799): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
04-22 17:48:06.972: E/AndroidRuntime(799): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-22 17:48:06.972: E/AndroidRuntime(799): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-22 17:48:06.972: E/AndroidRuntime(799):  at com.hspd.avhor.MainActivity.onKeyDown(MainActivity.java:41)
04-22 17:48:06.972: E/AndroidRuntime(799):  at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2609)
04-22 17:48:06.972: E/AndroidRuntime(799):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2375)
04-22 17:48:06.972: E/AndroidRuntime(799):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1847)
04-22 17:48:06.972: E/AndroidRuntime(799):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverKeyEventPostIme(ViewRootImpl.java:3701)
04-22 17:48:06.972: E/AndroidRuntime(799):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleImeFinishedEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3651)
04-22 17:48:06.972: E/AndroidRuntime(799):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2818)
04-22 17:48:06.972: E/AndroidRuntime(799):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-22 17:48:06.972: E/AndroidRuntime(799):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-22 17:48:06.972: E/AndroidRuntime(799):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
04-22 17:48:06.972: E/AndroidRuntime(799):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-22 17:48:06.972: E/AndroidRuntime(799):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-22 17:48:06.972: E/AndroidRuntime(799):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-22 17:48:06.972: E/AndroidRuntime(799):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-22 17:48:06.972: E/AndroidRuntime(799):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Post your logcat error please

Comment: A suggestion super.onBackPressed(); should be the 1st statement in OnBackPressed(). in the else part you can just finish the activity by calling finish()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to go back to previous page if back button is pressed in WebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6077141/6521116)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Override onKeyDown(params), check if the key pressed is back button ,check if the webview can navigate to previous page, if so naviagate to previous page. If there is  no web page to display you can finish the actiivty

You can use the below

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webView.canGoBack()) { 
            //if Back key pressed and webview can navigate to previous page
        webView.goBack();
            // go back to previous page
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        finish();
           // finish the activity
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Edit:

Remove the scrollview in xml layout. Try the below

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<WebView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/wv"></WebView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Edit:2

Here's a sample that works. Tested on samsung galaxy s3

activtiy_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<WebView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:id="@+id/wv"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 private WebView webView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
               public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                MainActivity.this.setProgress(progress * 1000);
               }
             });
             webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
               public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                 Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Oh no! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }
             });

             webView.loadUrl("http://slashdot.org/");

}   



@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webView.canGoBack()) {
        webView.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        finish();
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I replaced the code, but I still get the "Unfortunately, <app> has stopped." error.   
  
Logcat displays two errors:   
  
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) AND at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: remove the scrollview in xml . webview can scroll itself

Comment: Removed it and replaced it with RelativeLayout. My last comment was mistaken, logcat displays a whole lot of errors. Ill update the quoestion with them as there is no room in thos comment..

Comment: check the edit 2 a sample that is tested. Works on my device. posted the code also by putting the same under edit section

Comment: Your code works like a charm, Ill try to look back at my own mess of a code later when I am a more experienced coder. Thanks!