# Android - backbutton - restarting app

Tags: android, android-activity, webview, back-button

I designed a app with WebView.

Now I am facing issue, while clicking back-button of WebView of Android app. It is
restarting app instead of Homepage/Menu.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: post your webview class here

Comment: refer this link [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16152491/enable-back-button-in-webview

Answer (score 0):

1. I think you use the Intent to webview from Home activity.
2. if you use Intent, dont use finish() after start the Intent like below.

   ```
   Intent i=new intent(this,WebviewActivity);

   startActivity(i);

   HomeActivity.this.finish(); // dont use this line, it destroys homeactivity.
   ```
3. if you doesn't use the Intent, post your code clearly.

Hope this Helps.

Happy Coding :)