# Back button in android webview within a fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-studio-2.2, android-studio-2.0

I have created a webview within a fragment however when I am trying to press the  back button, it is killing the app instead of going back. What i want is to go back when i press the back button and if i am already on home page the back button should kill the app.

I have tried using all the solution in the given link.

[How to add "Go Back" function in WebView inside Fragment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10631425/how-to-add-go-back-function-in-webview-inside-fragment)

Please help.

Comment: What does'nt work with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26449424/3692099) approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the Activity's onBackPressed() method and check if there is any previous fragment in the backstack to pop back by calling getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate() or getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate() like the code below:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (!getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate()) {
        super.onBackPressed();        
    }
}
```

Don't forget to call .addToBackStack(null) before you call commit() to add the fragmenttransaction to the backstack.

And if you want to press back button to go back to previous webpage user has navigated in the WebView before go back to previous fragment, you can do this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
    } else if (!getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate()) {
        super.onBackPressed();        
    }
}
```

And remember to set your webView to load any webpage in the WebView by calling webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

Comment: dude seriously you are a genius... It really worked.. Could you  also help me with multiple fragmentes.. how can i use the onBackPressed if i have multiple fragments with individual webviews? Also what can i do to kill the fragment if it is opened through Navigation bar and go back to the main screen.

Comment: multiple fragments with individual webviews? meaning every fragments will have its own webview inside? Could you elaborate more on this?

Comment: I want to close the fragment and go back to the main activity from the app drawer with back button. is it possible. what do i have to do? I dont wish to change the above codes as it is helpful

Comment: Is the fragment is showing in another activity? so from there you want to back to main activity?

Comment: Fragment opens when i click on any option in navigation drawer but when I am pressing the back button, it is closing the app instead of going back to main activity.

Comment: If this is the case, you may use back the same code in the answer. I believe now your app is exit because you have not call .addToBackStack(null) when you show a fragment by clicking the option in the navigation drawer.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Web fragment and other fragments in your activity, this code works:

In your Activity:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        // Webview back
        if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_content) instanceof YourWebFragment){
            final YourWebFragment webFragment = (YourWebFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_content);
            if (webFragment != null){
                if (webFragment.onBackPressed()){
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        // Fragments back
        if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

In your Web Fragment:

```
public boolean onBackPressed() {
    if (webView.canGoBack()) {
        webView.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Reference:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19268540/1329094 and 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10631591/1329094

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin you can achieve this by adding [setOnKeyListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnKeyListener) to your WebView. This listener responds to clicks on the device's hardware buttons.

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    val myWebView: WebView = view.findViewById(R.id.your_webView)
    myWebView.webViewClient = WebViewClient()
    myWebView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com/")
    myWebView.setOnKeyListener { v, keyCode, event ->
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && myWebView.canGoBack()) {
            myWebView.goBack() // Navigate back to previous web page if there is one
            nested_scroll.scrollTo(0, 0) // Scroll webview back to top of previous page
        }
        true
    }
}
```

Comment: setonKeyListener is triggered twice. Need to add `event.action == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP` too. Also, if you navigates once, you can't close the app by using the back button.