# go to a specific page when the back button is pressed

Tags: javascript, android, html, back-button

I am developing an html app for android. I have some html files in my asset folder. The index.html file loads when app is started. In index.html I have a link to categories.html. When I choose any category and after pressing back button(hardware, there is no button in html) it goes to categories.html. But the problem is that I have option switch between categories from the categories, so when I press the back button it goes to the previous category.

For eg: I have 3 categories - green, yellow and red. I selected the category green. From green, switched to red, and from red to yellow. When I press the back button from yellow it goes to red. But it should go to categories.html

Is there any solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Search Google - [So many answers](https://www.google.ae/search?q=android%20webview%20override%20back%20button)
2. Search Stackoverflow - No need if you did step 1

   ```
   @Override
   public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
       if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
           switch(keyCode)
           {
           case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
               //open category page here
               return true;
           }

       }
       return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
   }
   ```

See [How to go back to previous page if back button is pressed in WebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077141/android-webview-how-to-code-the-back-button)

Comment: now the app closes when I press the back button. I did it in html using <a onclick=window.location.replace("url")>. But it doesn't works on Android. Is there any alternative for this ?

Comment: You need to post your efforts and what you've tried so we can help. If it's crashing then post the log too as that mostly tells you why it's crashing.

Comment: Its not crashing. It closes the app when back button is pressed