# Back button for previous page on android webview not working

Tags: android, webview, back-button

I am trying to override the back button so that it goes back the previous page but it just exits the application. Here;s the code.. please tell me where am i going wrong.

```
package com.example.thebase;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainAccelerometer extends Activity implements AccelerometerListener{

WebView myWebView;
//Back Button Code
     @Override
        public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                switch(keyCode)
                {
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                    if(myWebView.canGoBack() == true){
                        myWebView.goBack();
                    }else{
                        finish();
                    }
                    return true;
                }

            }
            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        }


//--------------------  


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.accelerometer_example_main);
    //ENABLING JAVASCRIPT CODE
            WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
            WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
            webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);


            //WEBVIEW CODE
              myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
            myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.pingcampus.com/greedy/get_category.php");


            //WebView client
              myWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());

              //Back Button

              //------


        };
//rest of the code
```

Comment: This is such a bad question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to go back to previous page if back button is pressed in WebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6077141/6521116)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have `onBackPressed()` method to override instead of `onKeyDown()`. Replace `onKeyDown()` with `onBackPressed()` as below:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (myWebView.canGoBack()) 
        myWebView.goBack();
     else 
        super.onBackPressed();

}
```

**EDIT**

Also check 3rd line in your onCreate()

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
```

You are declaring `myWebView` as local variable again and global variable is not instantiated which is throwing `NullPointerException` and crashes the app.

So change the your 3rd line of code as below:

```
myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
```

Comment: @TNR Should the above code block come withing the onCreate or outside of it?

Comment: @Arihant outside of onCreate()

Comment: I did paste it outside the onCreate but as i press the back button the app just gives error saying "Unfortunately this has stopped"

Comment: thanks! this is what saved my day:

"You are declaring myWebView as local variable again and global variable is not instantiated which is throwing NullPointerException and crashes the app."

Comment: Thank you for saying this: "You are declaring myWebView as local variable again and global variable is not instantiated which is throwing NullPointerException and crashes the app."!

Answer (score 2):

No need to check for `ACTION_DOWN`. Just:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // Check if the key event was the Back button and if there's history
    if( mWebView != null ) {
        if( (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && (mWebView.canGoBack()) ) {
            mWebView.goBack();
            return true;
        }
    }
    // If it wasn't the Back key or there's no web page history, bubble up to the default
    // system behavior (probably exit the activity)
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

or alternatively, instead of `onKeyDown()` you can override `onBackPressed()`:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if( mWebView != null ) {
        if( mWebView.canGoBack() ) {
            mWebView.goBack();
            return;
        }
    }

    return super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: Should the above code block come withing the onCreate or outside of it?

Comment: this is regular class method and should go outside of other methods (you cannot do it inside anyway)