# Application exits instead of navigating to previous page in WebView

Tags: android

can you please tell me why the application exit when I click back button of device.I am using webview .I go to one link "one.link" on clicking any on that page it will go to "next.link" then it goes to next page. But when I press back button my application exit.Not go to previous page  .It mean it not support history .

can we do that ?

I used this code `Layout.xml`

```
<WebView 
   android:id="@+id/webview"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

and `ApplicationLoad.java` is :

```
 public class ApplicationLoad extends Activity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.app);

            WebView browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
            browser.loadUrl("http://www.tutorialspoint.com");
        }           

    }
```

Comment: I think because you have called finish() in every activity remove it and try.

Comment: You should take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6077173/2668136 & http://stackoverflow.com/a/9743841/2668136

Answer (score 4):

By default Activity is suppose to be finished, so it is default behaviour, in order to do a custom task on back key press event, you need to override this method of your `Activity`.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(browser.canGoBack()){
         //if we can go back, just go back
         browser.goBack();
     }else{
         //let the parent handle it.
         super.onBackPressed();
     }
}
```

Make sure to make WebView your class field like this:

```
WebView browser;
```

and initialize it inside `onCreate();`

```
this. browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
browser.loadUrl("http://www.tutorialspoint.com");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            switch(keyCode)
            {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                if(mWebView.canGoBack() == true){
                    mWebView.goBack();
                }else{
                    finish();
                }
                return true;
            }

        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the `onBackPressed()` method and implement history navigation yourself.

Something like this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(browser.canGoBack()) {
        browser.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

This works for Android 2.2+, override `onKeyDown()` for older Android versions.

Comment: how can I achieve this

Answer (score 0):

thats how the back button wroks by default. it finishes the current activity. to go back to tge histoy you should override `onBackPressed`

```
 @Override
 public void onBackPressed() 
 {

    if (webView.canGoBack()) 
    {
        webView.goBack();
    }
    else
    {
            super.onBackPressed();
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy this snippet to your activity.

```
private WebView mWebView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mWebView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);

    // Do other things
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    //Check if the webview can go back
    if (mWebView.canGoBack()) {
        mWebView.goBack();
    }else{
    //This will finish the activity
    super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```