# WebView back button issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-webview

In my android application, I have coded like this; which is not fuctional for webview. On clicking BackButton leading to **app restart**.

Please help me

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && view!=null && view.canGoBack()) {

    view.goBack(); // go back in only the web view
    return true;
}


else  if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) { //Back key pressed

        if(counter<1)
        {

            Toast.makeText(this, "Press the back button one more time to quit the app",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            counter++;
        }
        else
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LaunchActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            intent.putExtra("EXIT", true);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33546673/back-button-kicks-me-out-of-the-app-on-webview/33547183#33547183

Comment: In my app homepage is Webview

Comment: You mean your first page is webview and if you press back button then app  is exiting? But you want to stay in same page ? am I right?

Comment: Assuming you use the device back button: Overwrite onBackPressed() in you activity.

Comment: @Amsheer: 1. Yes I want to stay in same page. 
2. Only for webview app is restarting for other android activities it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correct then you need to disable back button.

Try the following code:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
     if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
     //preventing default implementation previous to android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR
     return true;
     }
     return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);    
}
```

Or

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // Do Here what ever you want do on back press;
}
```

Comment: Check my code. I also wrote samething. But it is still restarting the app.