# How to go back to previous page if back button is pressed in WebView in Fragment?

Tags: android, android-studio, webview

```
public class PrimaryFragment extends Fragment {


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.primary_layout, container, false);
    WebView heroespage = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webView);
    WebSettings webSettings = heroespage.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    heroespage.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
    heroespage.loadUrl("http://beritagresik.com");
    return rootView;}
private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public  boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url ){
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }}}
```

This is sample my application, plis help for resolve this problem
thanks for ur help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to go back to previous page if back button is pressed in WebView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077141/how-to-go-back-to-previous-page-if-back-button-is-pressed-in-webview)

Answer (score 2):

If you open a web url in webview and inside is you open another link and so on.
now you want to come back by page , you can use webView.goBack();

Answer (score 0):

Try out this code:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                if (heroespage.canGoBack()) {
                    heroespage.goBack();
                } else {
                    finish();
                }
                return true;
        }

    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: Error for script heroespage.canGoBack() , heroespage.goBack() , super.onKeyDown
Thanks for answer sir