# Back Button Android WebView

Tags: java, android

First off, I don't really know anything about Java at all.. I do front end dev and that's really it, I have tried looking through documentation and tutorials but am having issues.. I have a website and I am trying to get it to work on Android. I have pretty much everything working except pressing back on an Android device exits the app (Which is expected from what i've read)

```
@Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            if (WebView.canGoBack()) {
                WebView.goBack();
            } else {
                super.onBackPressed();
            }
        }
```

Is what I tried adding to my code however I get the errors:

```
Error:(45, 24) error: non-static method canGoBack() cannot be referenced from a static context

Error:(46, 24) error: non-static method goBack() cannot be referenced from a static context

Error:(48, 22) error: cannot find symbol method onBackPressed()

Error:(43, 9) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
```

Many thanks in advance!

P.S - Here is the full code.

```
package com.appname.appname;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.view.KeyEvent;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.website.com");
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

    //Settings
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

}

private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    //Open links internally
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("www.website.com")) {
            return false;
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }

    //Back Button Fix

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (WebView.canGoBack()) {
            WebView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you.

EDIT: I had also tried this code I found in another Stack post.

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            switch (keyCode) {
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                    if (WebView.canGoBack()) {
                        WebView.goBack();
                    } else {
                        finish();
                    }
                    return true;
            }

        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

I was told in a tutorial to press ctrl+o (In Android Studio) and select an Override for onKeyDown, but that isn't in my list. I then found that the onKeyDown was for pre 2.0 Phones? So I tried looking for onBackPressed but I couldn't find that either. I know this is going to be something really easy..

Comment: this answer will help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/6077173/343679

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    if(WebView.canGoBack()){
        WebView.goBack();
    }else{
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

to:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    if(webView.canGoBack()){
        webView.goBack();
    }else{
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

**Explanation:**
You should call `canGoBack()` and `goBack()` for the webview *instance* that you're using (move to the previous view). This is also why the method is declared at the instance level and not at the class level (static)

**Update :**

declare global

```
 WebView myWebView;


 this.myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWebView);

  @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        if(myWebView.canGoBack()){
            myWebView.goBack();
        }else{
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

**Full code :**

```
 package com.appname.appname;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.webkit.WebSettings;
    import android.webkit.WebView;
    import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
    import android.view.KeyEvent;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

       WebView myWebView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        this.myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.website.com");
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

        //Settings
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    }

    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

        //Open links internally
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("www.website.com")) {
                return false;
            }
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }

      }


        //Back Button Fix

        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            if (myWebView.canGoBack()) {
                myWebView.goBack();
            } else {
                super.onBackPressed();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: @JesseWalby see my update answer with full code.Just copy and paste it.

Comment: Error:(44, 9) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    Error:(49, 22) error: cannot find symbol method onBackPressed()

Comment: @JesseWalby I have edited my answer now copy and paste it.

Comment: @JesseWalby glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this :

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (WebView.canGoBack()) {
            WebView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

from inside your inner class MyWebViewClient. It should be outside that class.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   ...
   ...
   private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
      ...
      ...
   }
   ...
   @Override
   public void onBackPressed() {
        if (myWebView.canGoBack()) {
            myWebView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.