# Why does the back button not work with this code?

Tags: android

I have an app in which I have a WebView where I display some websites. It works, clicking a link in the webpage goes to the next page in the website inside my app. But when I click the phone's back button, it takes me straight into my app. I want to go back to the previous page in the website instead. How can I do this?

Here is my code.

```
public class WebView extends AppCompatActivity {

private android.webkit.WebView webView;
private ProgressBar progressBar;
private LinearLayout layoutProgress;


@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.webview);

    webView = (android.webkit.WebView) findViewById(R.id.webViewMain);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    layoutProgress = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutProgress);
    webView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    settings.setSupportZoom(true);
    settings.setDisplayZoomControls(false);

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(android.webkit.WebView view, String url) {
            webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            layoutProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            progressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(android.webkit.WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            layoutProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }
    });
    if (isOnline()) {
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.**********.com/ ");
    } else {
        String summary = "<html><body><font color='red'>No Internet Connection</font></body></html>";
        webView.loadData(summary, "text/html", null);
        toast("No Internet Connection.");
    }
}

private void toast(String message) {
    Toast.makeText(WebView.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

private boolean isOnline() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected());
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(webView.canGoBack() == true) {
        webView.goBack();
    } else {
        WebView.super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Follow this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077141/how-to-go-back-to-previous-page-if-back-button-is-pressed-in-webview

Comment: I suggest you not to post same question thanks.

Comment: Question same but some code is different

Comment: Then I suggest you to maintain a cache queue in you application. When any link will clicked then you put the link in that queue and while Back button clicked you load URL from queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this add keydown**

```
 @Override
 public void onBackPressed() {

    if (webview.canGoBack()) {
        webview.goBack();
    } else {
        finish();
    }


 }

 @Override
 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        //Display confirmation here, finish() activity.
        if (webview.canGoBack()) {
            webview.goBack();
        } else {
            finish();
        }
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
  }
```

Comment: I Am working your code working fine... there is no problem.. can you so log when back press

Answer (score 1):

Check this code, this is help you

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    if(webView.canGoBack()){
        webView.goBack();
    }else{
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                .setTitle("Exit!")
                .setMessage("Are you sure you want to close?")
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        finish();
                    }

                })
                .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                .show();
        /*Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, SelectionActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();*/
    }
}
```