# physical back button not working in web view android.

Tags: android

physical back button not working in webview. When clicking on any url in web view, it is not taking me back to previous url. It is going directly to app. I have tried the following codes.

Ist method:

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

      if (webView != null) {
            if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && (webView.canGoBack())) {
                webView.goBack();
                return true;
            }
        }


        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

}
```

Second method:-

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (webView.canGoBack())
            webView.goBack();
        else
            super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6077173/3036824

Comment: thank you....issue is resolved for physical back button but when trying using back button on toolbar...issue still persists...any help would be appreciated...

Comment: You need to override activity's onBackPressed and implement the same login in onBackPressed.

Comment: Were you able to resolve the issue?

Comment: I removed that option...It was not required as physical button was working fine in my case....