# When modal popup is open, prevent mobile "Back button" to quit the site, close the popup instead

Tags: javascript, responsive-design, modal-dialog, back-button

When a modal popup dialog is opened, even if I add a close button (usually a X on top right), some users on mobile will use their mobile "Back button" to close the popup. But instead this will quit the site!

**How to make the mobile "Back button" close the popup instead of exiting the website?**

```js
document.getElementById("link").onclick = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  document.getElementById("popupdarkbg").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('popupdarkbg').onclick = function() {
      document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("popupdarkbg").style.display = "none";
  };
  return false;
}
```

```css
#popup { display: none; position: fixed; top: 12%; left: 15%; width: 70%; height: 70%; background-color: white; z-index: 10; }
#popupdarkbg { position: fixed; z-index: 5; left: 0; top: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: hidden; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.75); display: none; }
```

```html
<div id="main">
<a href="" id="link">Click me</a><br>
</div>
<div id="popup">This is a popup window! Click mobile "Back button"</div>
<div id="popupdarkbg"></div>
```

Notes:

- I've already seen this Codepen [How to disable browser back button using JavaScript](https://codepen.io/dhavalt10/pen/rGLBzB), but I'm not sure it it's cross-browser on Chrome, Firefox, Safari and on Android, iOS, etc.
- I've already seen answers about `window.onpopstate = function () { history.go(1); };` but I want to make sure this is the good practice to do it here, (so it's not a duplicate of them).

Comment: `pushState` is very well supported across various browsers and platforms, and this approach is a common practice. Unless you're specifically targeting IE9 or lower, you'll be fine.

Comment: @MátéSafranka so would you do `window.onpopstate = function () { history.go(1); };` only when popup is open and `window.onpopstate = function () { };` (or something else?) when the popup is closed so that, when the popup is closed, they can still go back to previous site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a rough version of how I do it in my apps:

```
var showModal = function() {
    // some code here to show the HTML elements...

    window.history.pushState('backPressed', null, null);
    window.history.pushState('dummy', null, null);
    window.addEventListener('popstate', hideModal, { once: true });
};

var hideModal = function(event) {
    if (event.state == 'backPressed') {
        // hide the HTML elements
    }
};
```

The reason I add two dummy states is because the `popstate` event also fires when the URL hash changes, e.g. when the user overwrites the hash manually in the address bar. Checking if the current history state matches `backPressed` lets me verify that the event was indeed triggered by the Back button.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works now when using it in Chrome for Android for example, but not when doing it from an app (my app is just an Android WebView displaying the website: the Back button quits the app).

Comment: Ahhh, well I'm afraid I can't help you with much certainty there. From what little I remember from Android dev, you'll probably need to capture the Back event in the Android app itself, and then use the WebView object's API to somehow notify the JS code on the inside. My guess (looking at the Android reference for WebView) would be to call `goBack()` to simulate the browser's Back button.

Comment: Thanks a lot again! Nota: the Android WebView part has been solved directly [by this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6077173/1422096).

Comment: @MátéSafranka I guess you have to pop the state if the user dismisses the modal via UI?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a minor variation of the accepted answer (*), that I'm finally using:

```
window.history.pushState('popupclosed', null, null);    // initial state: closed

var hideModal = function(event) {
    if (event.state == 'popupclosed') {
        closepopup();
    }
};

var showModal = function(event) {
    if (history.state !== 'opened') {
        window.history.pushState('opened', null, null);
    }
    window.addEventListener('popstate', hideModal, { once: true });
```

The difference with (*) is that here:

- we only add 1 new state per popup opening in the browser history, instead of 2
- in the case the previous popup was closed with the X top-right button of the popup (but not using "Previous in history" browser button or "Back button" on phone), then *when opening a second popup*, don't recreate a new history state `opened` because it's already the current state.

Comment: This answer seems to work fine.

Comment: Why do you use `history.state` in the condition and `window.history` in the statement below?
Is this on purpose or because of differences between `history` and `window.history`?

Comment: @Esger If I remember correctly it's the same, but for clarity I should put `window.history` everywhere.