# web view in fragment goes to home page every time to press back

Tags: android, android-fragments, webview, back

i have a problem with my web view in fragment that every time press back lead to home page can you help me to make back button goes to previous page .

my fragment jave file includes:-

```
package com.example.catalogmavbar.ui.cat;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import com.example.catalogmavbar.R;

public class CatFragment extends Fragment {

    public CatViewModel catViewModel;
    @Override

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cat, container, false);
        WebView webView = (WebView)view.findViewById(R.id.webviewncat);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.catalogmasr.com/categories");
        return view ;


    }


}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6077173/7804719 Try this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to go back to previous page if back button is pressed in WebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077141/how-to-go-back-to-previous-page-if-back-button-is-pressed-in-webview)

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function in fragment to control `webview.goBack()` that called by `onBackPressed()` in activity.

`Example`

in Fragment

```
CatFragment {
    ...
    public boolean onBackPressedHandled(){
        if (webview.canGoBack()) {
            webview.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

in Activity:

```
Activity {
    ...
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (!catFragment.onBackpressedHandled()) {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please help me to where exactly to add because its keep give me redlines and app crashes in debug

Comment: `1.`make a public method onBackPressedHold() for your catFragment. `2.` override onBackpressed() in your Activity which hold the catFragment. `3.`call `1.` method from `2.`