How to properly navigate a webview when the base URL isn't changing Jetpack Compose
I have a navbar with a back button that navigates through my application properly. There is a screen that opens a webview and I tried to edit the navbar so that it navigates within the Webview first before going back through the application.
However, I don't know how to make it recognize that url.com/start is different from url.com/differentSection. Unless the entire url changes (like to diffURL.com) any method I have been able to find doesn't recognize navigating through different sections of the same base url. I am assuming any built in functions I use to recognize the change only run when there's a complete page redirect.
I scrapped all my code and started over so any starting advice for this would be great.

Does it answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077141/how-to-go-back-to-previous-page-if-back-button-is-pressed-in-webview

To handle navigation within a WebView before navigating back through your application in Jetpack Compose, you need to manage the WebView's back navigation and your app's back navigation separately. Here is a simplified approach to achieve this:

Handle WebView navigation: You need to intercept the back button press when the WebView can navigate back within its history.
Handle application navigation: When the WebView cannot navigate back, the back button should navigate back through your application.

I attached sample composable below
@Composable
fun WebViewScreen(
    url: String,
    onBackPressed: () -> Unit
) {
    var webView: WebView? by remember { mutableStateOf(null) }

    BackHandler(enabled = webView?.canGoBack() == true) {
        webView?.goBack()
    }

    AndroidView(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        factory = { context ->
            WebView(context).apply {
                webViewClient = WebViewClient()
                loadUrl(url)
                webView = this
            }
        }
    )

    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        snapshotFlow { webView?.canGoBack() }
            .collect { canGoBack ->
                if (canGoBack == false) {
                    onBackPressed()
                }
            }
    }
}

